# Get updated_at timestamp for address

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, mysql, frontend, backend

1. Login to the frontend in a customer account.
2. Click on "Account information" and edit some information (firstname or lastname). Click on the save button.

Now go to the magento backend and click on customers -> manage customers.
Now you see the grid with the correct "updated_at" timestamp.

1. Login to the frontend in a customer account.
2. Click on "Account information"
3. Click on "Addressbook" and edit some information.
   Click on the save button.
   Now go to the magento backend and click on customers -> manage customers.
   Updated_at is not changed.

How can we set new updated_at timestamp for the address book also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. But i will check your code.
Thank you!

**observer.php**

```
<?php
class Easylife_Meta_Model_Observer 
{
    public function autoMetaDescription(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        if (!$address->hasDataChanges()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $customer = $address->getCustomer();
        //$_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
        //$_customer->setUpdatedAt(Varien_Date::now());
        //$_customer->save();


        try
        {
            $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read'); 
            $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
            $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $customerTable = $connection->getTableName('customer_entity');
            $write->update($customerTable, array("updated_at" => Varien_Date::now()), "entity_id=".$customer->getId());         
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            // $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}
?>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <easylife_meta>
                <class>Easylife_Meta_Model</class>
            </easylife_meta>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_address_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <easylife_meta>
                        <class>easylife_meta/observer</class>
                        <method>autoMetaDescription</method>
                    </easylife_meta>
                </observers>
            </customer_address_save_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the `customer_entity` as well as the `customer_address_entity` table have their own `updated_at` column.
This means those two values will be updated independent from each other.
The easiest is probably to trigger an update of the customer entity data.

Create a new module and add an observer on the `customer_address_save_after` event:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourName_Customer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </YourName_Customer>
    </modules>
        <models>
            <yourname_customer>
                <class>YourName_Customer_Model</class>
            </yourname_customer>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_address_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <customer_address_save_after_update_customer>
                        <class>yourname_customer/observer</class>
                        <method>afterAddressSave</method>
                    </customer_address_save_after_update_customer>
                </observers>
            </customer_address_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then create `YourName/Customer/Model/Observer.php` and add the `afterAddressSave` function:

```
class YourName_Customer_Model_Observer {

    /**
     * Save customer after customer address update
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function afterAddressSave($observer) {
        /** @var $customerAddress Mage_Customer_Model_Address */
        $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        $customer = $customerAddress->getCustomer();
        $customer->setHasDataChanges(true);
        $customer->save();
    }
}
```

If the update of the customer data does not work, you might consider adding `$customer->setSomeNonExistentProperty(true);` to the observer function.

*Note: The code above is not tested. It might needs some improvement to get it running.*